# Splitting a string into 2 strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I need help using the `Split` function in C#. The user needs to enter a 3 word phrase or more. I already know what the users first word will be. For example if the user enters 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2015', I already know the user will enter 'Microsoft'. How can I get `Split` to cut off the first word and give only the following phrase as a string?

Comment: `myString.Split(" ",2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) of the `String.Split()` method that takes an integer which splits a string into a maximum number of sub strings based on the characters in an array. It's parameters should be `char[]` and `int` like this:

```
string input = "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015";
string output = input.Split(new[] {' '}, 2)[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works great! But is there a way to only have the first word as i need to do that aswell. Thanks again

Comment: @Cabe You're Welcome. Use `0` instead of `1`. It returns only the first word.

Comment: @Cabe I also added a link to MSDN to read more about this overload.

Comment: Thanks again, this helped alot

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] separators = { ' ' };
string secondword = myString.Split(separators, 2)[1];
```

Will give you the right output. The split statement with an int argument specifies that you want to return at most 2 substrings, and the array index [1] directs the second of those (whatever is after the first space) to be your output.

If you need the first word you can do similar:

```
char[] separators = { ' ' };
string firstword= myString.Split(separators, 2)[0];
```

Comment: This is likely the most efficient and correct answer. I didn't even know this option existed, so learned something new. Nice.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio gives an error on the seccond argument of the `.Split` function (the 2) it says that "Argument 2: cannot be converted from 'Int' to 'Char'. " any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Replace()` method like

```
string str = "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015";
str = str.Replace("Microsoft","");
```

(OR) You can as well use `Substring()` method like

```
str = str.Substring(("Microsoft".Length + 1), str.Length - ("Microsoft".Length + 1));
```

Comment: It should be noted:  That will remove all instances of Microsoft in the target string, not just the first one, and also any substrings that appear, so "Microsofty" becomes "y"

Answer (score 1):

If you know the string will start with a value, you can just remove that number of characters from the string:

```
string value = "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015";
string expected = "Microsoft ";
if (value.StartsWith(expected))
{
    value = value.Substring(expected.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the first word, but you always want to take it out you can just use `String.Substring()`:

```
string input = "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015";
string result = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to slice and re-build the string, you could use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) to chop the string up, then [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) to skip past the first word, and then finally [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to build a new string:

```
var str = "Microsoft Visual Stuio";

str = string.Join(" ", str.Split(' ').Skip(1));
```